# JavaScript - Delete localStorage on last tab of a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, tabs

I am now working on `AngularJS` and using `$window.localStorage` to store an username of logged in user. As localStorage requires to be deleted explicitly, I am catching `$(window).on('unload', function(){})` as shown below.

```
$(window).on('unload', function(e) {
    console.log('closed');
    $window.localStorage.removeItem('user');
});
```

Unfortunately, `unload` event triggers when a tab is closed. The problem is, let's say I have 2 tabs of my webpage. When I close one tab, it will delete the `user` data, which is still needed in another tab, from localStorage. Is there anyway to detect closing the last tab of a webpage?

If no, is there any other way to overcome this? I am also trying to use `sessionStorage` instead. However, the storage is only working for one tab, so if I open the webpage in another tab, it requires to log in again.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with something like this:

set `$window.localStorage['tabCounter']` variable in localStorage, and do +1 every time you open tab for that app and -1 every time you close tab. In `$(window).on('unload')` check if `$window.localStorage['tabCounter'] == 0`, and in that case reset user.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried this trick and it works. However, do you have any idea how to handle refresh (as it triggers `unload` event first and reload)? It will be a problem as we decrease the tabcounter on `unload`

Comment: I believe there might be better solution, but mine would be this: When deleting user from localstorage, I would set cookie with duration of 30seconds or so with user data.... When loading site I would check if cookie exists and in case it does I would copy data back to localstorage... if it takes more than 30sec data is lost and it wasn't a refresh. @DarrenChristopher

Comment: @DarrenChristopher let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: That trick should work except the user open a new tab immediately after closing the last tab, that's why I would not using it. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion, appreciate it! As a temporary solution, I ended up not bothering it for now and use the logout button instead to clear the `user` from `localStorage` and redirect to login page.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need whatsoever for using `$window.localStorage` just use `localStorage` and check if there is no function unsetting your value. locaStorage is eternal unless deleted meaning its transcends your refreshes and tabs as long as they are all sitting on the same url ( and port )

Answer (score -1):

You could straight forward use "localStorage" instead of "$window.localStorage".
That way you will have localStorage on tab basis and whenever you will close any tab the local storage of that tab will be cleared.

Answer (score -3):

You can use

```
    $window.localStorage['user'] = null;
```

OR

```
    $window.localStorage['user'] = undefined;
```

Comment: The problem is not on `.removeItem()`, it is on the unload event, which triggers on tab close.